# Not able to install protobuf-compiler on macOS Big Sur

Tags: java, protocol-buffers, protoc

I am trying to execute `sudo apt install protobuf-compiler` on macOS, but I am not able to install the `protobuf-compiler`, nor to update the `apt`.

So far I tried, installing JDK, adding path to `./zshrc` and a few other things I searched on Google but no success. The picture below shows the error I get when I try to install `protobuf-compiler` or update using `apt`.

What might be the issue? Any answer is appreciated :)

[image]

Comment: I have never heard, that apt is available on macOS (at least not the package manager one might know from Ubuntu/Debian, if you really mean that). You can use homebrew as a package manager on mac.

Answer (score 2):

On MacOS, one of the most popular package managers is `homebrew`, and the command to invoke it is something like `brew install <packagename>`. For the protobuf package, it would be:

`brew install protobuf`